# Request into Rails App Significant Memory Increase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have identified an action in my Rails app that dramatically increases the memory used by the rails process, every single time I run it. Every time I refresh the screen the memory usage increases by a constant percentage, until the server runs out of memory and I am forced to restart the application.

The `#show` method executes the following:

```
def show
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  @result = @report.results
  @result = @result.paginate(page: params[:page]) if @result

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # run.html.erb
    format.json { redirect_to  "/results/#{@report.id}.json" }
    format.csv  { redirect_to  "/results/#{@report.id}.csv" }
  end
end
```

The problem line of code is `@result = @report.results`, which does:

```
def results
  filename = "public/results/#{self.id}.json"
  if File.exists? filename
    the_results = File.read(filename)
    return JSON.parse(the_results)
  end
end
```

Here, the problem is `JSON.parse(the_results)` where the .json file may be very large (an example file is 64 Mb). It appears I am loading the entire file into memory in order to pass it back to the controller, then the controller does pagination, which isn't good because if I'm only wanting to view 30 records in a view then I don't want to load everything.

I have two questions:

1. Why does Rails' memory continually increase in this case? The `FILE.read` + `JSON.parse` loads everything for my view, so Rails gets a ton of memory allocated to it to do this with. When I do it again I would expect that same memory (which is free to the Rails process) to be used for that reading, rather than Rails asking for more from the OS?
2. Is there a nicer way of doing this? I imagine I would want to only call `FILE.read` + `JSON.parse` only once, but where would it be cached? The controller?

Thanks for any help with this,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The part where a file is read and its content parsed may not be cached by default in the rails framework.

If it is possible at all, I would suggest making `@report.results` read from a database table instead of from the file. I am assuming you don't have the results objects mapped to an active record model yet. Might be a good idea to do that, as you get caching functionality baked in from the database.

Caching `FILE.read + JSON.parse` activity is theoretically possible, but I think is not practical. What if the file has changed since the last read and the file size and row count still the same, but some rows have different content? It would still require a full read of the file to confirm the content has not changed.